# No provider for Facebook (Ionic Native)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

> ERROR Error: No provider for Facebook!
>            &nbspat injectionError (core.es5.js:1231)
>            &nbspat noProviderError (core.es5.js:1269)
>            &nbspat ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2770)
>
>            &nbspat ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2809)
>
>            &nbspat ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (core.es5.js:2741)
>
>            &nbspat ReflectiveInjector*.get (core.es5.js:2610)
>            &nbspat AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.es5.js:3578)
>            &nbspat resolveDep (core.es5.js:11039)
>            &nbspat createClass (core.es5.js:10903)
>            at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10723)
>  View_MyApp_Host_0 @ MyApp_Host.html:1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `Facebook` in your `AppModule` (`app.module.ts` file):

```
// ...
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [...],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [...],
    providers: [
        // ...
        Facebook // <--- Here!
        // ...
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: which parameter i have  to write
facebook or FacebookModule

Comment: With just `Facebook` should be fine

Comment: but i have imort facebook sdk like this
import { FacebookModule } from 'ngx-facebook';

Comment: That's not Ionic native. If you want to use Ionic native, follow these steps: [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/). `ngx-facebook` is just another wrapper for the facebook sdk (when working with angular2 apps in the browser, where Cordova is not available).

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Facebook' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: You installed the wrong package. Please review all the steps from **[this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/)**

Answer (score 5):

Selected answer works till Ionic3. For **Ionic 4**+:
In *whichever* *module* has the component that uses FB login, add:

```
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
```

*[Note the /ngx]*

and add the provider for that @NgModule

```
providers: [ Facebook, .... ]
```

Comment: hero of the day. In ionic 5 the package it's @awesome-cordova-plugins/facebook/ngx